# ERROR: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: null

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I'm trying to run Hbase Shell on a new Hbase cluster on EC2 ( 1 master node and 8 slaves )

```
# jps
730 JobTracker
25961 HMaster
26622 Jps
25619 HMaster
810 NameNode
845 QuorumPeerMain

hbase-site.xml :
hbase.zookeeper.quorum=hbase-master

Hbase Shell :

hbase(main):003:0> status 'simple'

ERROR: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: null


hbase(main):005:0> create 't1','f1'

ERROR: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: null
```

Can you please assist what could be missing and how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your HDFS status is not correct,you can resolve it with these steps

1. Stop hbase and hadoop(master and datanode)
2. jps to show not released process in master and datanode(normally, your error caused by the hbase process not successful released )
3. Kill the process in step2
4. Restart hadoop and hbase